# Вывести слово, находящееся в фразе на определённой позиции

Tags: c

Понимаю, что пробел между словами в фразе по дефолту задаёт им позицию. Но вообще не приходит в голову, как реализовать такой код на C

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok

Comment: Позиция - это НОМЕР СЛОВА или НОМЕР СИМВОЛА его начала?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ищете в фразе разделители слов (пробел, запятая, тире и т.д. - в зависимости от задания). Если вам нужно например 3-е слово, то начало слова - это позиция второго разделителя + 1, конец слова - позиция 3-го разделителя. Примерно так работает функция `strtok()` - делит предложение на токены (слова).

Answer (score 0):

1. Вместо пробелов в цикле поставить 0 (или '\0'). Перед каждым пробелом получается можно взять указатель на начало слова.
2. Выделить память для указателей на слова.
3. В выделенной памяти обращаться по индексу.